# Do `on_finalized` and `on_initialize` impact block weight budget?

Tags: benchmarking, weight

- `on_initialize` returns a weight, but what is the effect of this weight exceeding block weight limit? Is the block valid? can extrinsic still be included?
- `on_finalized` does not return a weight, does that mean it always runs regardless of what remains of the block weight budget as a result of extrinsics+`on_initialize`

Answer (score 4):

Here is the schematical representation of the block weight:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌──────────────────┐┌───────────────────────────────────┐┌─────────────────┐│
││                  ││                                   ││                 ││
││  on_initialize   ││            extrinsics             ││   on_finalize   ││
││                  ││                                   ││                 ││
│└──────────────────┘└───────────────────────────────────┘└─────────────────┘│
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
 ◀─────────────────────────────────Block Weight─────────────────────────────▶
```

The `on_initialize` is privileged in a way that it can take how much weight it wants. If necessary, the logic there can take almost the whole budget without leaving anything for the extrinsics processing.

`on_finalize` is always executed and there is no way to skip that. `on_finalize` takes control after all extrinsics are executed. The problem is that whoever packs the block can fill up the extrinsics so that there is no space left for the `on_finalize` logic. That's why the convention is `on_initialize` returns the weight for itself and for `on_finalize`.

Substrate does not impose any hard limits on weight. However, Polkadot does. If a parachain validation function took more weight than alloted, such a block will be discarded.

Comment: Thank you.

Are you saying that in Substrate, `on_finalize` can even exceed the block weight limit?

Comment: @BedehoMender yes `on_initialize` and `on_finalize` can exceed the block weight and the block will still be valid.