# How can I make my node generate blocks only when they receive transactions?

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, block-production, finality, substrate-block-time

In substrate node template we can see that blocks are producing and finalizing if no transaction happening so how I can make my node to only generate blocks when there are transactions happening.

Comment: Same question, but without an accepted answer.

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/how-to-reject-empty-blocks

Comment: Some resources that you can refer about Instant Seal

+ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhkV0jAcWDY

+ https://substrate.recipes/kitchen-node.html

+ Configure service in Moonbeam

Comment: i noticed that if you use --dev option it does not generate blocks until other validators show up or you cast a transaction so that might be usefull for you to dig more how that works because you will understand the code more yourself in depth

Answer (score 1):

There are two consensus (or "block authoring" --whichever you prefer to call them) algorithms that might be exactly what you need:

1- [Manual seal](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/consensus/manual-seal/src/lib.rs): Where there is one author and it authors a block whenever you tell it via an RPC call.

2- Instant seal: Where there is one author and it attempts to author a block as soon as it sees a transaction in the pool, most often leading to one transaction per block

There is a [substrate seminar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhkV0jAcWDY) where they build a substrate node that uses manual seal and instant seal consensus.